# CSS apply n-th of type

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have multiple `span` elements and want to display the text at the following `span` positions (`10`, `19`, `28`, `37`) to be red.

I have tried the below;

```
span {
    &:nth-of-type(9n+1) {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Only thing is the first span also gets the CSS applied which I do not want. It should start with position `10`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this SASS? Apologies if not; I tagged it but then realised that I don't recognise whatever `9n+1` is trying to do... Anyway, I guess the observed behaviour is correct, and you could instead try `10 + 9n`.

Comment: Yes, it is SAAS...But you can treat it as normal CSS..nth-of-type

Comment: What about `9n+10` instead of `9n+1`?

Comment: Simply, it's documented that `n` is a counter that begins at 0, so if you have a constant offset, you need to include that offset in your expression.

Answer (score 7):

As you suggest – start with the offset of `10`.

```
span {
  &:nth-of-type(9n+10) {
      color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Dave suggested in his answer, you can use an offset of 10 or you can put another condition to exclude the first child

SCSS :

```
span {
      &:nth-of-type(9n+1):not(:first-child) {
          color: red;
      }
}
```

Snippet with CSS

```css
span:nth-of-type(9n+1):not(:first-child) {
      color: red;
  }
```

```html
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
<span>Span</span>
```